# Why does calling the stopSelf function from flutter_background_service cause flutter_vlc_player to crash?

Tags: flutter

I have created a very small Flutter app in which I'm using two packages ([flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service): 4.0.0 and [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player): 7.2.0)

I have a widget called MyHomePage in which I implemented the example from flutter_vlc_player. I also added a button which calls the ServiceInstance.stopSelf() function from the flutter_background_service package.

As soon as I press this button and try to navigate to a different page the VLC player throws the following error: PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null))

I've created this git repository to demonstrate the bug: https://github.com/Roel1l/myflutterapp/

Why does calling the stopSelf function from flutter_background_service cause flutter_vlc_player to crash?

Extra info:

- flutter version: 3.10.6
- dart version: 3.0.6
- my app is Android only

None of the fixes that come up when searching for this error seem to fix it.

I tried:

- Calling flutter clean, flutter pub upgrade outdated_package, flutter pub upgrade --major-versions, flutter pub outdated, flutter pub get.
- Added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to my android manifest
- Downgrading flutter_vlc_player to 7.1.2 (This actually fixes the bug but introduces a new one that happens when pressing the Android back button on the first screen and then reopening the app and navigating to the video page)
- Most fixes that come up when searching for this issue seem to be firebase related which I'm not using